# robot_localization: how to deal with imu data

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently, i am reading robot_localization and want to understand how it works. Previously, i have read and understood code and logics in robot_pose_ekf package.

I am confused about how imu data is processed in robot_localization. It seems to me that if config of differential was set to false, then imu can't work in robot_localization. The orientation of imu in 'world' fixed frame is transformed to orientation of base_link in 'world' fixed frame and set as measurement and send to ekf or ukf. But how can this data in world frame be fused with other data in other frame(such as 'odom' frame) ?

Hope i was wrong in understanding robot_localization and someone can fix me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326236/robot_localization:-how-to-deal-with-imu-data/) by [huchaohong](https://answers.ros.org/users/40059/huchaohong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2019-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Part of the problem is that IMU data lacks separate `frame_id` fields for orientation, angular velocity, and linear acceleration, so we have to make some assumptions.

Let's say your IMU's `frame_id` was set to the same value as your EKF `base_link_frame`. In that event, the filter would assume that all orientations are being reported in the EKF's `world_frame` parameter value, e.g., *odom* or *map*. If your IMU is rotated w.r.t. the *base_link* frame and the data is given in a frame like *imu_link*, then the filter will rotate the orientation data according to that *base_link*->*imu_link* transform, and then fuse it.

If you always want the orientation data to start at 0, turn on the `_relative` parameter for your IMU.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2019-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manmachine_x](https://answers.ros.org/users/53586/manmachine_x/) on 2021-08-11**:
Could I continue this thread? I understand that the orientation of an IMU is assumed to be reported in the `world_frame`, however what about the angular velocity of the IMU? Usually the angular velocity is reported with regard to its own frame or the `base_link`. However, I can see the transfer functions in the `ekf.cpp`  assume the fixed `world_frame` for angular velocities. Does this mean the angular velocity should be per-processed into `world_frame` by a rotation using its current orientation?

**Update:**
I read in https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/issues/165 that the angular velocity and acceleration are assumed in the IMU frame, then do you think this will conflict with the transfer functions that involves the angular velocity? Thanks!

**Final update:**
I have re-calculated and found everything correct (!!), after a friend reminded me that the Euler angle sequence is first psi along z, then theta along y, then phi along x, instead of the contrary^^ Thanks!